# The isotropy of the action of $SU(3)$ on $\mathbb CP^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-actions

Consider the action of $SU(3)$ on the complex projective plane $\mathbb CP^2$. How we can find the isotropy group?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $g\in\mathrm{SU}(3)$ stabilizes the $1$-dim complex subspace $\mathbb{C}\times\{(0,0)\}$ then it is a block matrix with blocks of sizes $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Ok, I found that the stabilizer is $S^1\times SU(2)$ so that means $CP^2=SU(3)/S^1\times SU(2)$. Now $S^1$ is a torus. Is $SU(2)$ the centralizer of this torus?

Comment: @Ronald Are you sure the stabilizer is $S^1\times SU(2)$? The lower $2\times 2$ block can be any element $h\in U(2)$ while the upper left block must be $(\det h)^{-1}$. Thus the isotropy subgroup is a copy of $U(2)$.

Comment: Written in a way that generalizes better, the stabilizer is $S(U(1) \times U(2))$; that is, it's the intersection of $U(1) \times U(2)$ (embedded block diagonally in $U(3)$) and $SU(3)$.